# Does a movie need a specific subtitle file?

Tags: windows-media-player

I have trouble trying to find a subtitle for the movie I downloaded. So I wanted to know if it is possible to make the subtitle file of the movie be copied to become a subtitle file of a another movie.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a subtitle file for another movie, just copy the file then give it the exact same file name as the movie (aside from the extension) and put it in the same folder as the movie, and Windows Media Player should read it. This normally works.

If this doesn't work, in the menu (for WMP 12, should be similar for older versions), ensure that **Play → Lyrics / Captions / Subtitles → On** is selected.

If this still doesn't work then perhaps the particular subtitle format isn't supported; grab the [DirectVobSub](http://www.codecs.com/directvobsub_download.htm) codecs or similar, install, and try again. More information can be found [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/this-is-how-you-can-add-external-subtitles-on-windows-media-player/).

If the subtitles of the existing movie you wish to copy from are embedded (e.g. an mkv file with a subtitle stream) you'll have to extract them, for which [there are various tools](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=extract+subtitles+from+movie), then you'll have a subtitle file to work with. If the existing movie is hard-subbed (that is, the subtitle text is rendered as part of the actual video image and not separate), though, then you're out of luck there.

Note that if the movies aren't exactly identical (e.g. one has a longer intro than the other, for example), then the subtitle timings might not be correct, and you may have to adjust them.

Comment: The last paragraph is the most important - often you find different versions of the same movie with different framerate or intro and then the subtitles don't match - they are too early/late (which is simple to fix) or they are too fast or too slow (which is hard to fix).

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said above, make sure the file name is exactly same as movie file name, keeping the subtitle file extension (srt, sub etc..)
if WMP still doesn't pick it up, try using a different video player like VLC or MPC-HC